# Is there a way to automatically apply a limit to a model?

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

### My Scenario

I have a DB with millions of rows. I only want to return a maximum of say 500 at any time. I know I can do this with the ->take(500) on the query when using Eloquent. However, what if I forget to add this?

That could result in the DB running a query for a long time resulting in performance issues for the users of the front end application.

### What I would like

I would like there to be a way to add an option to the model whereby anytime a query is ran using it, there will automatically be a limit of 500 rows returned.

My hope is there is something similar to the `protected $table = 'something';` that can be used to append to all the Eloquent queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes) to it.

For example, you would create a `LimitScope` as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class LimitScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->take(500);
    }
}
```

and then apply it to your model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Scopes\LimitScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new LimitScope);
    }
}
```